# Как отображать разные страницы в одном динамическом роуте?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, mongodb, nuxt.js

У меня есть в папке `pages/`  динамический файл `_slug.vue`. Я хотел бы, чтобы при запросе `mydomen.ru/что-то` выводилась либо страница статьи, либо страница профиля. У меня нет категорий, и запроса соответственно я тоже не хочу лишнего делать в виде этого `mydomen.ru/profile/Dmitry` или `mydomen.ru/post/privet` . Как можно это реализовать в nuxt?

Я нашёл только один выход. Использовать component и делать запрос на сервер и искать там по всей бд совпадение. И если оно нашлось, то выводить соответствующий компонент. Но для этого надо у каждого объекта (использую json ) иметь флаг к какому он типу подлежит. Либо это профиль либо статьи. Но это, мне кажется, не очень эффективно.

Comment: флаг “_classname” легко настраивается в монге. «к какому он типу подлежит» хорошее решение

Comment: А сама идея имеет место ?  Чтобы отображать компонент  в зависимости от запроса? Я использую мангуз